# Is there a built-in function or module that selects multiple phrases from a list that contain an overlapping word then keeps only the longest phrase?

Tags: python, string

I already looked up some forums here but nothing that caters to my problem specifically. I have a list:

```
listofwords = ['rick','rick sanchez','morty','morty smith sanchez','morty smith']
```

and my goal is to make a new list that has the shorter, overlapping words removed, like so:

```
newlist = ['rick sanchez', 'morty smith sanchez']
```

What I wrote was this:

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    count = 0
    for pos in range(len(string)):
        if string[pos:].startswith(sub_string):
            count += 1
    return count

listofwords = ['rick','rick sanchez','morty','morty smith sanchez','morty smith']
keeper = []
for i in listofwords:
    storage = ''
    for j in listofwords[1:]:
        if count_substring(j,i) == 1:
            if len(j) > len(i):
                storage = j
            elif len(i) > len(j):
                storage = i
            else:
                pass
    keeper.append(storage)

print keeper
```

and the output was:

```
['rick sanchez', '', 'morty smith', '', 'morty smith sanchez']
```

which was pretty close to what I was aiming for, except for the fact that I need to do the process for another round and clean up the list.

Please help me, is there a built-in module that is made for this kind of list organization?

Comment: "is there a built-in module that is made for this?" No. This seems like a pretty specific requirement that won't be covered by the generalizations of the builtin module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments say, this is pretty specific, it's probably not built in, but here's a one liner that computes what you want.

```
[word for word in listofwords if sum([word in a for a in listofwords]) <= 1]
```

This returns

```
['rick sanchez', 'morty smith sanchez']
```

Here's a quick description. The outer loop goes through each word and only chooses it based on a condition. The condition here is that the word is not a part of any other word in the list. If the word is a part of another word then the sum will be greater than 1. Thus, we don't choose it.

Hope that helps! Lemme know if you have any questions.

Comment: That's a packed line. I love it. Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly!

Comment: Better would be `if not any(word in a for a in listof words)`

Comment: @Barmar I don't believe that works, since each work will be `in` itself, so this will return false for every word and you will get an empty list. Would look prettier though, I'll give you that.

Comment: Ah, right. `word != a and and word in a for a in listofwords`

Comment: @Barmar that works, whichever way feels more natural I guess.

Comment: Or if you keep your list comprehension, use `len()` rather than `sum()`.

Comment: @Barmar not sure exactly what changes you mean, using `len` would only work if I changed it to something like `len([a for a in listofwords if w in a]) <= 1` but I guess that works too, I fail to see why its better though.

Comment: An approach with `any` and a generator expression will be much faster if you have a list with a lot of overlaps, since the first overlap is enough to disqualify a word. An example is the degenerate input `l = ["a" * i for i in range(2000)] `

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function with some *basic* short-circuiting logic to make this whole
affair more performant:

```
def remove_substrings(words):
    output_words = []
    for ind, word in enumerate(words):
        if not any(word in output_word for output_word in output_words):
            if not any(word in words[i] for i in range(ind + 1, len(words))):
                output_words.append(word)
    return output_words

words = ['rick','rick sanchez','morty','morty smith sanchez','morty smith']

print(remove_substrings(words))
print(remove_substrings(["rick"] * 2))
print(remove_substrings(["rick"] * 20000))
print(remove_substrings([*["rick"] * 10000, *["morty"] * 10000]))
print(remove_substrings([w for _ in range(10000) for w in ["rick", "morty"]]))
print(list(map(len, remove_substrings(["a" * i for i in range(10000)]))))
print(list(map(len, remove_substrings(["rick" * i for i in range(10000)]))))
print(list(map(len, remove_substrings(["a" * (10000 - i) for i in range(10000)]))))
print(list(map(len, remove_substrings(["rick" * (10000 - i) for i in range(10000)]))))
```

This has the expected output,

```
['rick sanchez', 'morty smith sanchez']
['rick']
['rick']
['rick', 'morty']
['rick', 'morty']
[9999]
[39996]
[10000]
[40000]
```

in quite reasonable time.

Its behaviour in the edge case where you have a repeated element is to retain
one of that element, which I think is a consistent way to behave. You can change
this to behave differently, if you like.

The idea here is that if we have previously rejected a word, we will not need to
consider it again, since it has been rejected on the basis of either a word that
we have already marked as correct, or a word occurring after it, both of which
have that word as a substring, so they will both work to reject other impossible
candidates.

Importantly, the use of the `any` function with generator expressions also means
that as soon as it finds a word that your current word is a substring of, it
stops looking for such words. This short-circuiting behaviour makes it faster
yet again.

I don't doubt that there is much more optimisation that can be done. Almost
certainly there is some sort of tree structure that reduces the time complexity
by some factor, but I think this is a decent start.